# Rspec matchers evaluating css?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I had some tests using capybara/rspec matchers to check content or links. Anyway, I just changed those to lowercase and used CSS to capitalize the first letter. Now all test fails because the raw html has `post` instead of `Post` although it looks like `Post`.

Is it possible to ignore case or check text after applying css?

Comment: How are you checking the css? Can you post the test?

Comment: I'm not testing the css. I just had a menu with a link `<a ...>Post</a>` then I changed it to `<a ...>post</a>` and added the css `a:first-letter { text-transform: capitalize }`. I'm using `click_on` and `have_content`.

Comment: I just don't want to change all my scenarios to lowercase because it's more readable as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Capybara supports regular expressions:

```
find('a', :text => /post/i).click
```

You might need to use `click_link` or `click_on`

[Reference on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ruby-capybara/u5iZ6W1H_98)